# Devstack installation on Ubuntu Error ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openstack, devstack

I am trying to install devstack on Ubuntu 16.04. I have tried on the newest verision on Ubuntu as well (other systems CentOS, Fedora), but always I am stuck on an error after ./stack.sh.I have new 16.04 on VM and now I have this error ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/stack/.cache/pip/wheels/ab/a3/97/d6831ba72a8b63e81f32d89267dd866d7984d32ede93210ee3'
2019-10-19 21:32:52.130 | Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

I have tried many solutions that were placed on the Internet, but none of them worked. Please provide me some support. Thank you

Comment: Found any solution for this problem. I am still facing this issue with Ubuntu16.04 with pike version.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried adding your user to sudeors?

add this line `<username> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` to    /etc/sudoers.d/

this would give your user sudo privileges.

Also I had the same problem installing devstack and I changed my ubuntu version to 18.04 following [openstack documentation](https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/) and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

you may try this:
useradd -s /bin/bash -d /opt/stack -m stack
echo "stack ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" | sudo tee /etc/sudoers.d/stack